# Find files not read for 30 days in linux

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to find out the files which are sit idle for the last 30 days i.e. file which are not read for last 30 days.

I am confused which one will be the appropriate option to use here.

```
find $dir -atime +30

or 

find $dir -mtime +30
```

Can you please help me out here or point me to the correct function to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [`find(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Answer (score 1):

`atime` refers to latest access date. The file was accessed but don't modified (read only)

In change, `mtime` refers to latest MODIFY date. The file was accessed and modified (read and write)

Comment: Note also that on Linux, the filesystem may be mounted with the `noatime` option, in which case access times are not available.

Comment: Yes, but he only ask for command options, not filesystem details

Comment: The question is how to find files by access time.  I'm just trying to point out that your answer, while correct, is useless if the filesystem does not track access times (a somewhat common, though not default, configuration).  Good answer anyway.

Comment: @JohnZwinck will track the access time too.. does 'stat' command help in that case?